# Storyboard design with landscape and portrait

Tags: ios7, storyboard, xcode5.1

I already designed the portrait story board without **auto layout** but I want to design land scape too.
any one can you give the suggestion please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the view in the ViewController as a container and have a view for portrait and a view for landscape.

I would suggest autolayout, I think it is the best option for that kind of situation.